# How do I properly nest while and for loops in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

Just learning javascript and having a hard time with this code would like to make it repeat 5 times different random math questions but only continue to the next question if answered correctly. can somebody help point me in the right direction?

```
// var initialization
var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
var correct = num1 + num2;
var guess = 0;
var count = 1;
var msg = " ";
//var debug = 5;

// loop basic math process

while(count <= 1){

guess = eval(prompt("What is "+num1+" + "+num2+" = __ ?"));

    if(guess != correct){
        msg = alert("Sorry please try again");

    }else{
        msg = alert("By George I think you got it!");

        for(i=0;i<=5;i+=1){
            alert(debug);
            var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
            var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
            var correct = num1 + num2;

            guess = eval(prompt("What is "+num1+" + "+num2+" = __ ?"));

        if(guess != correct){
            alert("Sorry please try again");

        }else{
            alert("Great your on a roll!");

        }}} count++;
}
```

Comment: Put `count++` inside your `else` condition after `alert('Great you're on a roll!)`.

Comment: thanks for such a quick response.

Comment: use console.log( ) for output for debugging purposes; it is far superior to alert ( can show bojects, elements, etc directly in a good browser, not just the dreaded `Object [object]`.  For that matter, use the error console to see error messages too!  The code you posted runs fine - as long as I fix the `alert(debug)` which throws an error in chrome.

Comment: `eval` should be avoided like the plague, until you're experienced enough to argue intelligently against that position.  As the examples below show, you don't need to evaluate the result of `prompt()` at all.  Your code has the amusing side-effect of evaluating any expression I put into the answer - most hilariously, I can literally enter `12 + 45` if it asks me what the sum is, and it will evaluate the addition and I don't even have to do the math!  You hardly ever, almost never, need `eval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep asking until they get the question right, then you are going to need two loops.  One to count the 5 questions.  And one inside of the that to keep asking the question until it is correct I think you have your loops kind of inverted.  I would instead do something like the following:

```
for(i=0;i<=5;i+=1){
    alert(debug);
    var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
    var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
    var correct = num1 + num2;
    var guess = -1;

    while (guess != correct) {    
        guess = eval(prompt("What is "+num1+" + "+num2+" = __ ?"));
        if(guess != correct){
            msg = alert("Sorry please try again");
        }else{
            msg = alert("By George I think you got it!");
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to know if they got several right in a row to change the message you would have to detect if they were on a streak:

```
var streak = 0;


    while (guess != correct) {    
        guess = eval(prompt("What is "+num1+" + "+num2+" = __ ?"));
        if(guess != correct){
            msg = alert("Sorry please try again");
            streak = 0;
        }else{
            streak++;
            if (streak < 2) {
                msg = alert("By George I think you got it!");
            } else {
                msg = alert("Keep up the good work!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your coding, I suppose you don't need the outer **while** loop.
And if you do need while loop to control the total rounds of **for** loop, you should better wrap the whole **for** loop code in an individual function.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a hint -- if your editor doesn't have the ability to reformat/re-indent source code, jsbeautifer.org does a wonderful job.

```
var num1;
var num2;
var guess;
var correct;
var msg;

// Bonus
// It looked like you were trying to give different responses so it wasn't 
// quite as boring

var successMessages = [
  "Way to go!",
  "Alright!",
  "Cheers!",
  "Tally ho!"
  "Well done, old boy"
];

var questionsLeft = 5;

// loop basic math process
while (questionsLeft !== 0) {

  num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  correct = num1 + num2;

  guess = prompt("What is " + num1 + " + " + num2 + " = __ ? ");
  guess = parseInt(guess, 10); // Convert to a number

  if (guess !== correct) {
    msg = alert("Sorry please try again ");
  } else {
    msg = successMessages[questionsLeft];
    questionsLeft--;
  }
}
```

Or, if you want to make them repeat the question:

```
var num1;
var num2;
var guess;
var correct;
var msg;
var isRight;

// Bonus
// It looked like you were trying to give different responses so it wasn't 
// quite as boring

var successMessages = [
  "Way to go!",
  "Alright!",
  "Cheers!",
  "Tally ho!"
  "Well done, old boy"
];

var questionsLeft = 5;

// loop basic math process
while (questionsLeft !== 0) {

  num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  correct = num1 + num2;

  // They haven't answered yet, so they can't be right.
  isRight = false;

  while (!isRight) {
    guess = prompt("What is " + num1 + " + " + num2 + " = __ ? ");
    guess = parseInt(guess, 10); // Convert to a number

    isRight = guess !== correct

    if (isRight) {
      msg = alert("Sorry please try again ");
    } else {
      msg = successMessages[questionsLeft];
      questionsLeft--;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah still familiarizing myself with sublimetext editor. thanks for advice i'll try jsbeautifer.org out the next time i post on here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var num1 = [], num2 = [], correct = [], count = 0, guess;
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
  num1[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
  num2[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
  correct[i] = num1[i]+num2[i];
}
while(count < 5){
  quess = prompt('What is '+num1[count]+'+'+num2[count]+' ?');
  if(+quess === correct[count]){
    alert('You are Correct!');
    if(++count === 5)alert('You Have Completed All of the Answers Correctly!!!');
  }
  else{
    alert('Please Try Again.')
  }
}
```